# SQL query report indicating no sales

Tags: sql

Hello helpful Stack Overflow community - I am having some troubles trying to figure out this query I'm working on. It may seem simple, and hopefully it is, but i'm just learning at the moment. My query is supposed to come up with a list that shows which customers do not have any orders? Include contact information so that the sales department can follow up with these customers. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
select c.CustomerID 'Customer ID', c.CompanyName 'Company Name',
c.ContactName 'Contact Name', c.Address, c.City, 
c.StateOrRegion 'State Or Region', c.PostalCode 'Postal Code',
c.Country, c.Phone, c.Fax, o.OrderID 'Order ID', 
o.ShippedDate 'Shipped Date' 
from orders o 
left join Customers c 
on o.customerid = c.customerid
where o.shippeddate is not null
order by c.ContactTitle asc
```

Thanks again for taking the time and helping!

Comment: I've removed the incompatible database tags - please tag the database you're *actually* using.

Comment: `right join` instead of `left join` and change `o.shippeddate is not null` to `o.shippeddate is null`  you're current logic says.  Return all orders and the related customers where items have been shipped.  What you want is return all customers where items have not been shipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where not exists (select 1
                  from orders o
                  where o.customerid = c.customerid
                 )
order by c.ContactTitle asc;
```

Also, you should not use single quotes for column aliases.  They should only be used for string and date constants.

There is definitely no need to include order information, for non-existent orders.  I used `select *` just as a shorthand instead of listing out the columns that you might want.

Comment: Appreciate the help and educating @Gordon Linoff and SqlZim - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have your table order backwards and your `is not null` should be `is null` to find `customers` that do not have `orders`.

Or you could change your `left join` to a `right join` and still change `is not null` to `is null`.

```
select c.CustomerID 'Customer ID', c.CompanyName 'Company Name',
  c.ContactName 'Contact Name', c.Address, c.City, 
  c.StateOrRegion 'State Or Region', c.PostalCode 'Postal Code',
  c.Country, c.Phone, c.Fax, o.OrderID 'Order ID', 
  o.ShippedDate 'Shipped Date' 
from Customers c 
  left join orders o 
    on o.customerid = c.customerid
where o.shippeddate is null
order by c.ContactTitle asc
```